# AngularJS 1.2.0 $resource PUT/POST/DELETE do not send whole object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm using angularjs 1.2.0 with $resource. I would like to have some PUT/POST instance actions that doesn't send the whole object to the server but only some fields and in some cases totally no data.

Is it possible? I searched everywhere but couldn't find anything

**UPDATE:**

It also happens with DELETE requests:

Given this code:

```
group.$deleteChatMessage({messageId: message.id}, function(){
    var i = _.indexOf(group.chat, message);
    if(i !== -1) group.chat.splice(i, 1);
});
```

The request is this:

[image]

See how the whole model is sent (under "Request Payload").

This is the resource:

```
    var Group = $resource(API_URL + '/api/v1/groups/:gid',
      {gid:'@_id', messageId: '@_messageId'},
      {
        deleteChatMessage: {method: "DELETE", url: API_URL + '/api/v1/groups/:gid/chat/:messageId'},
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$resource(SERVER_URL + 'profile.json',
{},
{
    changePassword :
    {
        method : 'POST',
        url : SERVER_URL + 'profile/changePassword.json',

        // Don't sent request body
        transformRequest : function(data, headersGetter)
        {
            return '';
        }
    }
});
```

You could customise exaclty what is sent to the server by implementing your own code in the transformRequest function.  In my example I was adding a new function to the REST client, but you can also overwrite existing functions.  Note that 'transformRequest' is only available in version 1.1+

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http for that specifically. However, I have one case I use for a project that might help. Also my example is returning an array from the server but you can change that.

In my service:

```
app.factory('mySearch', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/items/:action', {}, {
        search: { method: 'POST', isArray: true,
            params: { action: 'search' }
        }
    });
}
]);
```

In my Controller:

I can build up custom params to post to server or if its only two fields I need from a table row the user selects.

```
        var one = "field_one";
        var two =  "field_two";
        $scope.search({one: one, two: two});
```

Then I can post those through an event and pass the custom params

```
    $scope.search = function(customParams) {
    mySearch.search({query: customParams}, function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;

    }, function(response) {
        console.log("Error: " + response.status);
    })
};
```

Hopefully this was some help. Let me know if this is close to what your looking for and I can help more.

POST
[image]

DELETE
[image]

Comment: But this way params are passed in the url but mainly I don't want any params or only the ones speicified by me to be sent in the request body not in the url

Comment: hmm. well if I console.log(customParams) its only fields I specify. I could only post a single field if I tell it to. I am doing this with Rails so my route is doing a custom search specified by the fields and I need to save it for other purposes.  Sorry I am a bit tired too about to sleep. Will try again later today. gluck.

Comment: try logging from rails what it gets from the browser in the request's body

Comment: I have sending actually 4 specific fields, origin, the radius, destination, and radius of that. http://pastebin.com/ayxNzH05

Comment: if you're using rails try this blog post. towards the bottom the author is using $resource as an example as well. I have harder time reading coffeescript though..
http://bit.ly/18sHOWi

Comment: See here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource, "non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
" doesn't allow post data to be specified but only parameters. Instead class actions: "non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
"

Comment: I added some screenshots. Are you $resource calls setup as a service?
with app.factory? I'll create an example with your setup soon and add another answer.

Any reason why you're passing API_URL and the full url structure as well?

Comment: $resource is is set up correctly, which method are you using fro the delete request in the above screenschot?

Comment: I made a pastebin of my exact code. http://pastebin.com/WUAbHVAX
I am using ng-grid module so don't let that confuse you. the row parameter is being passed through a ng-click="delete(row)"

Sorry once i get freed up at work ill make a better example.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the "problem": you're using a class method not an instance one (your delete is attached to the resource not to the model that has to be deleted) and in class methods you can specify the request body. i want to do this in an instance method

Comment: Yeah I noticed that later with your delete method while trying to see if I can setup an example. I was also moving a demo app to staging yesterday to start testing and I broke the server. So was busy troubleshooting that... Hope you solved it.